# Convergence of continued fractions with negative decreasing terms

Tags: combinatorics, convergence-divergence, continued-fractions

Let $a_n>0$ be a decreasing sequence of real numbers and consider the continued fraction 
$$\cfrac{ 1}{ 1- \cfrac{a_0}{1- \cfrac{a_1}{1- \ddots}}}.$$
Is there any criteria for such continued fractions to converge? The most applicable criterium I have found so far is Worpitzky's theorem which guarantees convergence whenever $\max a_n \leq  1/4.$ However, this result is far more general since it is concerned with complex valued $a_n$.

The specific case we are interested in is finding the domain of $x$ that gives convergence in the above continued fraction with
$$a_n = a_n(x) = \frac{2}{(2 + (n+1) x)(2 + (n+2) x)}.$$
So, $a_n =O(n^{-2})$ and $a_{n+1}/a_n \uparrow 1$.

Comment: Just apply the theorem to a tail of your continued fraction (starting with large enough $n$; it then converges). You get that the values of $x$ it diverges at are basically poles of the limit function (and no *general* criteria will ever tell you what these are).

Comment: Thanks. Make sense. Can we infer anything about continuity of the limiting function?

Comment: Yes (through establishing uniform convergence, for which you need a quantitative version of the theorem, or to do a quantitative analysis of the proof you have). One could go further for analyticity...